# Does cAdvisor use binary or decimal system when reporting bytes

Tags: metrics, cadvisor

I am using cAdvisor v0.44.0 to expose container metrics which are collected by Prometheus and visualized in Grafana. One of the cAdvisor metrics is `container_network_receive_bytes_total`. Let's say that its value is `554325454`. Should bytes reported by cAdvisor be converted to MB with decimal or binary approach?

1. `554325454 bytes` = `554.3254539999999 MB` (decimal)
2. `554325454 bytes` = `528.6459484100342 MB` (binary)